# Extend vector and call the push_back function

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

So for a task for school we have to implement Linear Hashing as a class which derives from a vector containing a unique pointer towards a block list class.

Now whenever I try to add an element using push_back I get: `No matching member function for call to 'push_back'`. However when I try to run `this->size()` it does work.

My Code:

```
template <class Key, class Data>
class Linhash : public std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Blocklist<Key, Data>>> {
public:
    Linhash<Key, Data>(Disk<Block<Key, Data>>* disk) 
    : std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Blocklist<Key, Data>>>() {
        this->disk = disk;
    }

    void add(Key k, Data d);
};

template <class Key, class Data>
void Linhash<Key, Data>::add(Key k, Data d) {
    // This works
    this->size();

    // This doesn't work
    Blocklist<Key, Data> bl(this->disk);
    this->push_back(bl);
}
```

My bet would be that I am pushing the wrong object to the push_back function (that it has something to do with unique_ptr's) but I am not sure. Also we did not learn unique_ptr's in our class but got thrown into it while doing algorithms which makes it really hard for me to understand this well.

Comment: You have a vector of one type (`std::unique_ptr<Blocklist<...>>`), but you are trying to `push_back` a value of a different type (`Blocklist<...>`)

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the blocklist in a unique pointer?

Comment: So I would have to create a unique_ptr object separately?, edit: Ok, imma try that, edit #2: that worked, thank you so much!

Comment: `push_back(new Blocklist<Key, Data>(disk));` I think this should work. If not, make it more explicit: `push_back(std::unique_ptr<Blocklist<Key, Data>>(new Blocklist<Key, Data>(disk)));` Also, a few strategically placed `typedef`s will make your life easier.

Comment: That worked, thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by Igor Tandetnik, I just had to wrap it in a unique_ptr object and that did the trick.

So the working code:

```
template <class Key, class Data>
class Linhash : public std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Blocklist<Key, Data>>> {
public:
    Linhash<Key, Data>(Disk<Block<Key, Data>>* disk) 
    : std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Blocklist<Key, Data>>>() {
        this->disk = disk;
    }

    void add(Key k, Data d);
};

template <class Key, class Data>
void Linhash<Key, Data>::add(Key k, Data d) {
    // This works
    this->size();

    // This doesn't work

    this->push_back(std::unique_ptr<Blocklist<Key, Data>>(new Blocklist<Key, Data>(this->disk)));
}
```